# How do I import an animated SVG file in Next.js 13 while maintaining transparency and animation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js

Importing an animated SVG file in Next.js 13

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex h-screen flex-col items-center">
      <div className="container mt-12 flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 px-4 py-8">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/blaze-hero-animation.svg">
          svg hero animation
        </object>
      </div>
      <Image
        src="/images/blaze-hero-animation.svg"
        alt="hero animation"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

The object tag gives me my animated svg however the background color is white (the original svg has a tranparent background. The image gives me my transparent svg but without any animation.
Do I need to use SVGR or something? This is in Next.js 13.

I just want to import my transparent animated svg file. id prefer not to mess with SVGR since I don't think I should have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a React component that encapsulate your SVG like this:

```
//LinkArrowIcon.tsx
type Props = {
  className?: string;
};

export function LinkArrowIcon({ className, ...props }: Props) {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={24}
      height={24}
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      className={`w-full h-auto ${className}`}
      {...props}
    >
      <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
      <path
        fill="none"
        stroke="currentColor"
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeWidth={2}
        d="M11 7H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h9a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-5m-7 1L20 4m-5 0h5v5"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

```
//Home.tsx
import LinkArrowIcon from "./LinkArrowIcon";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex h-screen flex-col items-center">
      <div className="bg-dark dark:bg-light text-light dark:text-dark">
        <LinkArrowIcon className="w-6 h-auto" />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here I'm using Tailwind CSS combined with themes in order to decide if the SVG should be colored with either light or dark colors (`-light` and `-dark` are just custom colors).
Also checkout the [React SVGR website](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) that automatically converts an SVG into a React component.

**N.B.**
I've faced an issue while running `next build` with Typescript over some SVGs that has tags like `<set>` inside their body.
I've tried different solutions, but none of them seems to work correctly, so I've just replaced the file extension from `.tsx` to `.jsx` and the build went fine.